# How to recursively duplicate doubly linked list C++

Tags: c++

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong here.

//Recursively duplicate the list.

```
    void duplicateNodes(const SortedList& o, Node * const copyIter) {

        if (copyIter != NULL) {
            o.add(o.head, copyIter->data);
            duplicateNodes(o, copyIter->next);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Neither can we if you do not tell use what is wrong with it.

Comment: Or what `SortedList` etc is

Comment: Since `o` is const, it seems to be the source, but you seem to be treating it as the destination, and `copyIter` as the source.

Comment: Your parameter o is `const`

Comment: _@ms01249_ Post a [MCVE] please, otherwise your "question" is unanswerable.

Comment: Also probably not a good idea to use recursion for this.

Comment: My error is that 2 overloads have no legal conversion for 'this' pointer

Answer (score 0):

What does the method "add" do? Does it add a node to end or the beginning of the list?

Also, are you trying to create 2 sorted lists or simply double every node in a list? See below:

Original List: A->B->C

2 Lists: A->B->C & A->B->C
Double Every Node: A->A->B->B->C->C

Comment: It is supposed to add at the specified index                                                /* Recursively adds the node to the list. */
virtual void add(Node * const after, const E& o) {} Also it is just a copy of the original list. Not double every node in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Move your `const` to the 2nd parameter:

```
void duplicateNodes(SortedList& o, Node const * const copyIter)
```

You are modifying the first parameter, so it can't be `const`.